# Why do I get an error from this sub query script?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem pertaining to a sub query and left joining from other table.

[image]

Code:

```
SELECT effectiveDate,

    (SELECT

      CASE
        WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED' THEN log
      END

    FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40'
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' GROUP BY effectiveDate

    )

    FROM schedules
    LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40'
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Comment: your query gives error 1242, i.e it returns more then 1 row

Comment: what do you mean for that?

Comment: What is the subquery supposed to be returning? It's telling you to limit your query to one row with a 'select top 1'

Comment: The error message can't get any clearer.  It specifically tells you that your subquery returns more than 1 row.  How to fix it?  Make sure your subquery returns only 1 row.

Comment: Also you tag `MySQL`, but your query looks like `SQL Server`.  Please tag properly.

Comment: I think the asker is duplicating himself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340585/why-i-get-error-says-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-in-selecting-other-column

Comment: @Eric what suppos to be to do? what should i replace from my script?

Comment: @GeorgeMuncal What's your inner query doing?

Comment: @GeorgeMuncal..Your inner query should always return only one row.Can you post your schema and how the data looks like in all the tables that your are using.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?? Coz the inner query and the outer looks the same !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why i get error says Subquery Returns more than 1 row IN Selecting other column in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340585/why-i-get-error-says-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-in-selecting-other-column)

Comment: Ex. I used the sub query script for select every category. so i want to select Category 1 in different condition. Category 2 in different condition. so on.

Comment: Hello @GeorgeMuncal I mean to say that the subquery is returning more then one row so you need to manage it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your actual query is

```
 SELECT effectiveDate,
 CASE
        WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED' THEN log
      END
     FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40'
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' GROUP BY effectiveDate.
```

Not sure why you're using a subquery

Comment: I used sub query for select every category , Category 1  , Category 2 , Category..

Comment: CASE
        WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED' THEN log
      END
     FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40'
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' GROUP BY effectiveDate                               this condition for category 1. so now how to select again for another category?

Comment: What do you mean by category ??I dont see any column called 'category' that is used in your query

Comment: What i mean , I want to select different condition. CASE WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED' THEN log END FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40' AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' and counter = 1  ---- FOR CATEGORY 1 then I want to select new category CASE WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED' THEN log END FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date WHERE schedules.empid='40' AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(effectiveDate) ='1' AND counter= 2

Comment: Actually you question is simple one.But i dont understand your requirement.Can you run the above query i have posted in the answer and show me the result.Attach a screen shot of the result after running the query.